Relation between Chow groups and K theory
I am reading about Chow groups and algebraic K-theory of schemes. I get to know that for smooth schemes the re is a strongly convergent spectral sequence
$$E_2^{p,q} = CH^{-q}(X,-p-q) \implies K_{-p-q}(X).$$
I am wondering that does this kind of spectral sequence is also true over algebraic stacks?
Can anyone provide any reference to these things?
Thanks in advance.
